# Can't add existing Form and User control C#

Tags: c#

I want to add existing User control and Form but I can't. Please give me a solution

[Image 1. Solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmBFH.png)

[Existing User control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsFeU.png)

Comment: you need to give us more information. what did you try until now? are you getting error message?

Comment: I try to coppy existing file to folder of new project. And it doesn's has file .rex and designer.cs and In code doesn't has method InitializeComponent()

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you paste the x.cs, x.Designer.cs, x.resx files into your project.
2. Check if you include them in the project. 
   The simple method is to copy the relevant files directly, and then right-click in the solution project, so that all the files are included in the project. Of course, you can also open see all files options and then include these files in the project
3. The InitializeComponent() method is generally in x.Designer.cs. If it is indeed in the x.Designer.cs file and you have not copied it, you will definitely not find it.